# always on top form but requires message boxes and combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, modal-dialog, messagebox

I have a form that is set to always ontop. I force this every 500 ms via a timer shown below in code.
The timer is being started from a child thread.

The form  has to raise an error sometimes but this is not modal and the users ends having to click it twice - once to make it modal and once to acknowledge it (if they do it fast enough)

The user can also bring up a combobox that is in a panel in the main form but when selecting this, the dropdown becomes clear again, as a result of the timer making the form modal(the same effect as if the user just clicked away from the combobox).

How can i fix the Messagebox that it is modal?
How can i fix the combobox that it continues to list the items within it without clearing
thanks
damo

**timer to make form always on top**

```
// Restore the form.
this.Visible = true;
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
this.Show();
```

**messagebox**

```
MessageBox.Show(this,"hello world", "myApplication");
```

Comment: Is the only use of the timer to set the form back on top?

Comment: yes - its only job is to make the form always on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the timer before and reenable after showing the messagebox:

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
MessageBox.Show(this,"hello world", "myApplication");
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

This of course can be in a method so you won't have to duplicate code:

```
public void ShowMessage(string title, string message)
{
   timer1.Enabled = false;
   MessageBox.Show(this,message, title);
   timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Since `MessageBox.Show` is a blocking command, timer will only be reEnabled after the MessageBox is closed

Comment: i hear what you are saying about the blocking command but it doesnt make a difference. the focus on that messagebox is lost as if the timer keeps running. my enabling of the timer initially is called from  a seperate thread which may explain the issue?

Comment: Lets start by you posting more code in your initial question. Specifically, the exact declaration of the timer and how you enable it...